# CAN BUS - ACK field (singular or multiple response?)

Tags: pic, can-bus

I have several ECAN within the PIC18 and PIC24 (on OpenCan) with Can Transceiver attached to the CAN Bus network. In event one module send a message and received by other modules (within ECAN), will all ECAN do CRC check and if passed, make dominate bit or just one one of many make this response?. In other words, does PIC ECAN make ACK response even the message is not assigned for that module?

Comment: What do you mean by "message not assigned for that module"? How would you assign a message to a module?

Comment: I feel like some answers are mutually exclusive. Not sure which answer is the correct one

Answer (score 1):

CAN controllers generate dominant ACK bits if they receive the frame without any errors. ID filtering takes place after that. So yes, the CAN controller generates ACK even for the frames it's not interested in.

If a transmitter detects dominant ACK bit, it concludes that at least one node in the bus has received the frame correctly. However, it's not possible to determine if this receiver was the intended one.

As far as I understand, ACK bit makes it possible for a transmitter to self-check. A transmitter can think "If no one hears my message, then I should be the one having problems." if it samples recessive ACK bits. The reception of the message by the intended node should be checked by higher layer protocols, like CANopen.

Answer (score 0):

Transmitter node transmits CAN MSG and monitors the bus for a dominant bit in the ack. slot. Receiver if receives the message correctly, will overwrite the ack. bit and make it dominant. If it does not receive the message correctly, it will not overwrite the ack. slot. Then the transmitter knows that one node has not received the message correctly because it will detect a dominant bit written by the other nodes and assume that all the nodes have received the correct message. Even if one node does not receive the data correctly the message is retransmitted by the transmitter.

Check if you can successfully transmit CAN messages. The problem you could have is in receiving messages. When you send a message to PIC, the message is not received. The message received flag is never set. You have to check that a message is being sent with the scope, check if your PIC stores it. Check which mode is it in, I assume 0, and if it is configured to receive all messages, even with errors.

Check on the scope if the PIC sends and receives the Ack response. When a message is then transmitted back to the pic, check if it sends an Ack response or receives the message!

Answer (score 0):

CAN is a broadcast network so a node does not really know how many other nodes share the bus with it.

With that manner, all the nodes shall do the CRC check and ACK whether the messages are "assigned" (supposed to be received in application layer) by the listened node or not.

There are no conflict, since if there a error with CRC or ACK, all listened nodes shall send (active or passive) Error Frame which are same form from every nodes.

I recommend you to refer this excellent article:
http://www.copperhilltechnologies.com/can-bus-guide-error-flag/